# Jython issue with classpaths

Tags: jython

I had a question on the diffrence of running two commands related to jython. I'm having issues with classpath and db drivers.

What works for me is doing the following:
jython -J-classpath ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar test.py /home/test/data

Running that command everything runs as expected so I wanted to combine my scripts to be run as a jar so not to require jython. Once I finshed creating my jar everything runs until it comes to the point where I need the driver and returns a driver not found error.

I run this as the following:
java -cp ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar mytest.jar test.py /home/test/data

I'm not sure I understand why one would work and the other would not work?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but I'm not sure why it works. I hope someone can explain to me. I rebuilt my mytest.jar jar and included the needed classpaths in the mainifest when building the jar and this seems to allow me to use in java as:
java -cp mytest.jar test.py /home/test/data

Why would including the classpath in the mainfest instead of at the command line produce diffrent results?

Comment: When you run java programs via Ant, beanshell, Jython, or whatever, in some cases classes are loaded in a custom classloader instead of the "default classloader".  For example, starting a beanshell script and then dynamically loading the jar within the script causes the .jar to be loaded into a custom classloader and classes that need to loaded with Class.forname method, like JDBC drivers , will therefore have trouble in the environment.  As long as you load stuff into the default classloader though, you wont have problems.